# Branch locus of finite morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a Galois morphism of smooth projective surfaces branched over a smooth curve $C\in Y$. Consider $C'=f^*C\subset X$ a non-reduced divisor in $X$. Let $C''=(C')_{red}$ the reduced curve. Is it true that $C$ and $C''$ are isomorphic?

Also $f_* O_X(C'')$ is a vector bundle on $Y$. What exactly is this vector bundle? Can we explicitly say?

Comment: To the first part, the answer is no in general, unless $\deg f=2$. Second part is difficult to answer unless you explain what exactly you mean by explicit.

Comment: @Mohan, we have a morphism $C''\rightarrow C$ . It is finite of degree one right? And both are smooth curves? Doesn't it mean they are isomorphic?

Comment: @Mohan, by explicit i was wondering if there is a decomposition of the direct image into components? Can we describe the components invariant under the action of the Galois group of the cover?

Comment: For the first, $C''\to C$ may not be degree one (as I said if $\deg f\neq 2$). For, the latter, you are assuming Galois, not just finite. I still do not know what you mean by describe the components.

Comment: @Mohan, i see. I will assume that the map is Galois. So, i am just guessing here, is $C''\rightarrow C$ an etale map? For the second, we can decompose $f_*O_Y=O_X\oplus L$. The Galois group acts as identity on $O_X$. Is there a direct sum expression for $f_*O_X(C'')$ where we can point out what the component is which is the eigen space corresponding to identity for the action of the group